# How to open port for a specific IP address with firewall-cmd on CentOS?

Tags: centos, firewall, centos7, firewalld

I would like to open port `4567` for the IP address `1.2.3.4` with the `firewall-cmd` command on a CentOS 7.1 server.

How can I achieve this, as the documentation I could find was too specific on this?

Comment: First install and start firewalld service `sudo yum install -y firewalld && sudo systemctl start firewalld`. Then open port 80 and 443 (and ssh 22 for remote shell if needed) (use _--permanent_ flag to keep changes after system reboot) `sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=80/tcp && sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=443/tcp && sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=22/tcp`. Then reload firewalld service to activate new configuration `sudo systemctl reload firewalld`.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Try this command

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-rich-rule='
  rule family="ipv4"
  source address="1.2.3.4/32"
  port protocol="tcp" port="4567" accept'
```

Check the zone file later to inspect the XML configuration

```
cat /etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml
```

Reload the firewall

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks for your useful and simple answer!

Comment: The change won't take place immediately unless you subsequently run `filewall-cmd reload`

Comment: The correct way to reload is actually: `firewall-cmd --reload`

Comment: I think you should be using single quotes after --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="1.2.3.4/32" port protocol="tcp" port="4567" accept'

Comment: Is there no way to accomplish the same with a service file so that public.xml can remain unedited (e.g. multiple service files rendered from templates)?

Comment: incidentally this is pretty much the ONLY WAY TO ADD IPV6 rules also, work to the wise, for those ready to dive in.

Comment: While this solution will work, @michael-hampton's solution is the most firewalld-esque way to do this. In my opinion, rich rules should be used as a last resort when there are no better ways to do something.

Comment: I completed the RHCSA much after this answer, and I agree. Avoiding rich rules would lead to a more maintainable configuration down the line.

Answer (score 92):

Create a new *zone* to accommodate this configuration. FirewallD zones are defined by source addresses and by interfaces.

```
firewall-cmd --new-zone=special --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
firewall-cmd --zone=special --add-source=192.0.2.4/32
firewall-cmd --zone=special --add-port=4567/tcp
```

Add `--permanent` of course to the latter two commands to make them permanent.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Agreed, this is the best answer IMHO. In order to list that zone, use ```firewall-cmd --list-all-zones```. Also, you may want to add ```--permanent``` to both --add statements.

Comment: I agree with this as well, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This is perfect!

Comment: this should be the accepted answer

Comment: I have a problem with this (maybe), the moment you add a source and a port to the special zone, it becomes active all the time for traffic coming from that source, doesn't matter if you are home, in the airport, or at starbucks. Does that make sense??

Comment: Which set of rules would apply if source address is 192.0.2.4 and port is NOT 4567 ?

Comment: I guess "default" which rejects connections even if "public" has some allowed ports. This is why "rich-rule" is a better answer.