# Can Someone Explain Why this firewalld Command Does Not Work as Expected?

Tags: firewall, nat, port-forwarding, firewalld

matiu asked the question of how they can do port forwarding for a single source IP address. You can read the original question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/756138/how-to-port-forward-with-firewalld-depending-on-source-ip/756139).

I provided the following commands as an answer. I based my answer on research of firewalld commands and my existing knowledge of port forwarding with Cisco routers. I realize Cisco is a completely different platform than firewalld but I suspected the concept of an ACL and then NAT would be similar enough for my answer to work. Based on matiu's feedback that was wrong.

Can anyone explain why the firewalld commands below does not result in only source IP address 1.2.3.4 being allowed to pass the firewall and then be port forwarded from TCP 22 to TCP 5678?

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-rich-rule="rule 
family="ipv4" \
source address="1.2.3.4/32" \
port protocol="tcp" port="22" accept"
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=external --add-forward-port=port=22:proto=tcp:toport=5678:toaddr=*private translated IP address*
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Comment: Your firewall rules are attached to different zones.

Comment: Well that is a typo on my part. So good to know. If I then changed the port forward rule zone from external to public would this work?