# How to remove access to a port using firewall on Centos7?

Tags: firewall, port, centos7

Had a port opened up to for public use using firewall-cmd, I wanted to limit this port to a specific IP which I found the answer for on this [SITE](https://serverfault.com/questions/684602/how-to-open-port-for-a-specific-ip-address-with-firewall-cmd-on-centos/).

I used the following to open it:

```
$ firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=10050/tcp
$ firewall-cmd --reload
```

Now using the information from the information I found I wanted to restrict access to this port to a specific IP address. Do I need to first remove this port from public access?

Or Can I just just add the new rule as follows and that will take care of the problem for me?

```
$ firewall-cmd --new-zone=special
$ firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=special --add-rich-rule='
  rule family="ipv4"
  source address=”123.1.1.1"
  port protocol="tcp" port="10050" accept'
```

I have tried the following:

```
$ firewall-cmd --zone=public --remove-port=10050/tcp
$ firewall-cmd --reload
```

But when I run the following:

```
$ firewall-cmd --list-ports
```

`10050/tcp` is still displayed.

Please understand I'm not overly familiar with Sever side configurations.

**Soultion:** Do not forget the **--runtime-to-permanent**

```
$ firewall-cmd --zone=public --remove-port=10050/tcp
$ firewall-cmd --runtime-to-permanent
$ firewall-cmd --reload
```

Comment: Ah I forgot the **--permanent**

Comment: You should post this as an answer (and accept it). It is perfectly acceptable to accept your own answers, this way the question is marked as solved.

Comment: It's better to _not_ use `--permanent`, in case you make a mistake with a firewall rule. If you used `--permanent` and locked yourself out, you will find it quite difficult to get back in, since you have no way to recover. Instead, don't use `--permanent`, and when you are happy with the rules, use `firewall-cmd --runtime-to-permanent` to commit the rules. If you get locked out, reloading the firewall or rebooting will go back.

Comment: So can this `firewall-cmd --runtime-to-permanent` is applied after the `firewall-cmd --reload` or does it replace it entirely? I am going to definitely try this.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**Solution:** Do not forget the **--runtime-to-permanent**

```
$ firewall-cmd --zone=public --remove-port=10050/tcp
$ firewall-cmd --runtime-to-permanent 
$ firewall-cmd --reload
```

Comment: I still had to follow with `systemctl restart firewalld`.

Comment: This did not work for me. `systemctl` is version `219` and `firewall-cmd` is version `0.5.3` on CentOS 7.5 64bit.

Answer (score 13):

```
# firewall-cmd --zone=public --remove-port=12345/tcp --permanent
# firewall-cmd --reload
```

Replace 12345 with the port you want to remove.

Comment: I read somewhere that in Fedora doc, it suggests to put `--permanent` as the first option. But yes, `--permanent` is the key.

Comment: I usually keep it as the last option to ensure that if the rule is incorrect for whatever reason, I can simply reboot without making the rule permanent. If it does what I want, I can up-arrow and add `--permanent` to the end.

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps, you will be fine:

```
$ firewall-cmd --zone=public --remove-port=10050/tcp
$ firewall-cmd --runtime-to-permanent 
$ firewall-cmd --reload 
$ systemctl restart firewalld
$ firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-ports
```

Comment: I don't think you need to restart firewalld, `firewalld` was actually designed to avoid restarting all the services every time you change a configuration.

Comment: actually for me only restart helped.

Comment: For me firewall-cmd --zone=public --remove-port=1883/tcp --permanent followed by a rfirewall-cmd --reload was the effective sequence

Answer (score 2):

Please Running these step

1. firewall-cmd --permanent --remove-service=telnet
2. firewall-cmd --reload
3. systemctl restart firewalld.service
4. firewall-cmd --list-all
5. iptables -nvL

your iptables firewalld willbe not showed service telnet

Regards

Answer (score 1):

All those answers were wrong on my fedora server. My solution was:

```
firewall-cmd --remove-port=8081/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
firewall-cmd --list-all
```

Please note that the command `firewall-cmd --permanent --remove-port=8081/tcp` was throwing an error "**firewall-cmd: error: unrecognized arguments: –-remove-port=8081/tcp**".