# Using Centos Firewall how to assign multiple IPs to a Port?

Tags: firewall, port, centos7

Setting up a new zone, with a port that has [restricted access to an IP address](https://serverfault.com/questions/684602/how-to-open-port-for-a-specific-ip-address-with-firewall-cmd-on-centos/). How does one apply this to more than one IP?

```
$ firewall-cmd --new-zone=special
$ firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=special --add-rich-rule='
  rule family="ipv4"
  source address=”123.1.1.1"
  port protocol="tcp" port="10050" accept'
```

Is source address allowed an array of CSV? Is it defined like this?

> source address="123.1.1.1","234.1.1.1"

Comment: The second solution in your linked question seems to be more appropriate for this case.

Comment: I see what you mean, I can just call the single cmd line and it will add it to the existing zone.
`firewall-cmd --zone=special --add-source=231.1.1.1`

Comment: @GeraldSchneider if i define multiple IPs to a zone do I have to set the server to that zone for it to take effect? Or is `firewall-cmd --reload` perfectly acceptable?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider - I found the answer in the solution that I linked.

Comment: Unfortunately the accepted answer in the question you linked is... rather wrong. Check the other answer instead. See also the question I've marked as a duplicate, for the thorough explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a rich rule for this. It's unnecessary and too complicated for what you want to do.

Just add the source IP addresses and desired ports to the zone directly.

For example:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=special --add-source=192.0.2.123
firewall-cmd --zone=special --add-source=198.51.100.7
firewall-cmd --zone=special --add-source=203.0.113.81

firewall-cmd --zone=special --add-port=10050/tcp

firewall-cmd --runtime-to-permanent
```

Comment: What does the last action `firewall-cmd --runtime-to-permanent` do?

This is the second solution in the link. :) I eventually implemented it this way. I did try the first method though and I encountered an issue. Which is why I posted this question, but I was advised to use option 2. Which I did. :) I will accept your response though as the correct one. For it is the correct solution.

Comment: @mcv It saves the running configuration and makes it permanent...

Comment: so i placed the --permanent inside each statement, is that also okay? If I restart the firewall will this configuration load automatically?

Comment: Did you not see the [other comment](http://serverfault.com/questions/818996/how-to-remove-access-to-a-port-using-firewall-on-centos7#comment1042710_818996) I left on your other question?

Comment: Thanks looking at it now. this is all new to me and the documents I have read do not discuss this `--runtime-to-permenant`.