# Allow TCP traffic on port 3306 from ip range

Tags: centos, firewall-cmd

I have problem with firewall-cmd on Centos 7. I have task:

```
Allow TCP traffic on port 3306 from ip range 192.168.1.0/24, make sure to add this rule as second rule in the chain
```

and second task

```
Allow TCP traffic on port 80 from ip range 192.168.1.0/24, make sure to add this rule as first rule in the chain
```

It's a tasks which i find in google for linux training.
These are tasks that I found on the internet to practice the firewall, but I can't do it.

I tried like this:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --add-source=192.168.5.0/24 --add-port=3306/tcp
```

but i got error

```
firewall-cmd: error: argument --add-port: not allowed with argument --add-source
```

In iptables i can do with this kind

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3306 --source 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

but how can i do this in firewall-cmd?

Regards Pawel

Comment: You're gonna need to use richrules or zones as suggested in this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/684602/how-to-open-port-for-a-specific-ip-address-with-firewall-cmd-on-centos)

Comment: @GeekyMasters Ok, thank you very much for help :)